# Subtract constant to all element of array with assembly sse without intrinsics

Tags: c, assembly, simd, sse

I have an array of number from 0-255. I want to calculate `255 - elem` for each element in the array **with inline assembly in C** using **SSE instructions**.

this is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(){
       __declspec(align(16)) float a[5] = {250, 18, 48, 16, 15};
       __declspec(align(16)) float constant = 255;
      
       _asm{
          movups xmm0, [a]
    
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

how can I do that ?

actually I know I can do this:

```
    int main(){
        const array_number = 5;
        __declspec(align(16)) float ff = 4;
       __declspec(align(16)) float a[5] = {250, 18, 48, 16, 15};
       __declspec(align(16)) float b[5] = {255,255,255,255,255};
       __declspec(align(16)) float res[5];
      
       _asm{
          mov ecx, array_number
          movups xmm0, [a]
          movups xmm1, [b]
          subps xmm1, xmm0
          movups [res], xmm1
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

but if array `a` size grows I hove to increase numbers in array `b`.

Comment: What compiler are you programming for?  What version of SSE can you use?  Do you really want to use inline assembly and not intrinsic functions for this?

Comment: @fuz compiler is: x86 MSVC v19.latest, sse version2, yes I have to use inline assembly.

Comment: @fuz sorry it's sse version 1

Comment: MSVC v19.latest is from 1990. If you upgrade to a semi-modern C compiler you could be using `_Alignas(16)`. Anyway, leaving the code in main() like this causes modern compilers like gcc or clang to conjure 64 bit magic numbers out of C code doing stuff like `res[i] = 255 - a[i]`. As in the whole calculation is moved to compile-time like it should. You might have to rewrite this example into a function solution to make sense of it. See this https://godbolt.org/z/d6ET4dn43

Comment: Last time you asked this, you were using integers (32-bit for some reason despite your 0..255 data range), and you were using GNU C inline assembly. (And mentioned you had some assignment requiring you to use inline assembly, not intrinsics, so you couldn't do it the normal efficient way).  What are you actually try to do?  Like what requirements do you have to satisfy with this code?  What are you hoping to learn from this exercise?